# Debugging: working with generated Java code instead of Xtend code

Tags: eclipse, xtend

When I debug Xtend code, I would sometimes like to see generated Java code with all the intermediate variables. However, even if I set a breakpoint inside this code, debugger shows Xtend code instead. Is it possible to switch to Java code in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, There is no way to turn off xtend debugger yet.

However, Open a "Generated Code" View in Debug Perspective may help you.
It shows breakpoints too(synchronized with breakpoints on xtend file), It makes us understand co-operation with java more easy.

Answer (score 5):

I've just found this video: [Debugging in Xtend and Java - side by side](http://vimeo.com/38425995), 00:15.
The source is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150214123434/https://www.eclipse.org/xtend/new_and_noteworthy/index.html#debugging), at section **Debugging since M6**:

> Debugging through Xtend and Java is now fully supported. Setting breakpoints in Xtend works just as in Java and you can even switch to the Java level whenever wished by a context menu action.
>
> Also all the cool features known from the Java debugger, like ‘Display’, ‘Inspect’, or ‘Exception Breakpoints’ are available."

You can witch between Java and Xtend with the "Show source" option from the context menu of any stack frame in the debug view.